# sqlalchemy recursive common table expression (cte) not equal to pure postgre recursive cte

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I have some data (**0**) and want to calculate the path to the root with sqlalchemy. My PostgreSQL (**1.1**) query worked as espected (**1.2**).

But when i transform this logic to SQLAlchemy (**2.1**) i do not get the full path (**2.2**)?

**0 Database**

```sql
INSERT INTO category(id, path, parent_id)
    VALUES(1, 'A',null),
    (2,'B',1),
    (3,'C',2),
    (4,'D',3),
    (5,'E',1);
```

**1.1 PostgreSQL Query**

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE path AS (
    SELECT id,
        path,
        parent_id
    FROM public.category
    WHERE id = 4
    UNION
    SELECT c.id,
        c.path,
        c.parent_id
    FROM category c
        JOIN path p ON p.parent_id = c.id
)
SELECT path
FROM path;
```

**1.1 PostgreSQL Result**

| path |
| --- |
| D |
| C |
| B |
| A |

**2.1 SQLAlchemy Query**

```py
topq = session.query(Category)
topq = topq.filter(Category.id == 4)
topq = topq.cte('cte', recursive=True)
bottomq = session.query(Category)
bottomq = bottomq.join(topq, Category.parent_id == topq.c.id)
recursive_q = topq.union(bottomq)
q = session.query(recursive_q).all()
```

**2.1 SQLAlchemy Result**

```py
[(4, 3, 'D')]
```